# HTML-only browser for Android? (skip all resources, load just base page/HTML)

Tags: browser, html

For example, I have [tuned my desktop Firefox browser](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/janakaud/js-for-firefox/master/keyconfig/README.md) to skip loading JS, CSS, fonts etc.; but here I'm asking for something much simpler: when I enter a URL or click a link on an existing page, browser should simply load the page pointed by that URL, and not any other resources that are referenced inside it. Basically, a *HTML-only browser*.

I'm not looking to just *disable* CSS etc. (e.g. unlike the "No style" option of Firefox, which *loads* the CSS file and *only skips the rendering* step). I want the browser to *completely avoid loading* the linked resources. (Saving bandwidth is one main goal.)

I'm well aware that this would break functionalities of several websites, not to mention "ugliness" from lack of CSS; but the site(s) that I wish to access are already tested to work fine in desktop under HTML-only rendering conditions.

I have tried many of the "custom" browsers on Google Play, but none seems to contain something resembling a HTML-only mode.